# create phonegap app in eclipse/cordova vs 'Adobe phonegap build'

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I created an app in 'Adobe phonegap build'. This app was pretty slow when running it (lagged when pushing buttons etc)

Some years ago, I built a phonegap app only using eclipse with cordova. This app was also a bit slow, but I felt it was a faster than the one I created using 'Adobe phonegap build'

Have anyone tested, or read documentation that states that 'Adobe phonegap build' creates 'slower' apps than creating one by your own in eclipse with cordova?

In advance, thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I know that if you build a jQuery mobile app + PhoneGap can be slow, but not always.

But if you use good design patterns, and less DOM manipulation the app will be much faster :-)